Azure ARC: RDP through windows admin center preview to a non default rdp port server
We've started testing Azure ARC and we'd like to know if there's a way to specify a non default RDP port when starting a remote desktop session from Azure Arc machine page (windows admin center preview).
Everything works out great when we use the default RDP port (ie, 3389). However, our servers are configured to listen to RDP sessions on a different port and I can't seem to find a place where to set this information on the Azure Arc Windows admin center.
Thanks.
